# FreeCad addon manager

Tags: kicad

I'm trying to install the KiCad addon in FreeCad to create a footpring from DFX.The Freecad  [wiki page](https://wiki.freecad.org/Std_AddonMgr) says it's done through the AddonManager that's in the Tools menu since version 0.17. I'm on 0.20.1. Any ideas?

[image: Tools menu]

Comment: Do you have Addon Manager in Edit --> Preferences?  Version 0.21 is out, try that.

Comment: Nope, it's not there either.

Comment: I think your installation is broken somehow.  Try version 0.21, that definitely has the Addon Manager, plus many new and improved features.